# Defining Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a "weird" situation here. I need to handle following routes in the same way:

```
domain.com/common/p1
domain.com/common/p1/p2
domain.com/common/p1/p2/p3
```

Which means, basically, route should be something like:

```
Route::get('common/{path}', function ($path) {
    //should execute for all paths after common
});
```

Is there any regex which I can use?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters).

Your code would look something like:

```
Route::get('common/{path1?}/{path2?}/{path3?}', function ($path1=null, $path2=null, $path3=null) {
    //
});
```

For unlimited parameters use:

```
Route::get('common/{path?}', 'Controller@Method')->where('path', '.*');
```

This will result in an array of paths in your controller method.

Answer (score 2):

See more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

You can use:

```
Route::get('common/{path}', function ($path) {
    //should execute for all paths after common
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel routing component allows all characters except /. You must explicitly allow / to be part of your placeholder using a where condition regular expression:

```
Route::get('common/{path}', function ($path) {
    //should execute for all paths after common
})->where('path', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can..

```
Route::get('common/{path}', function ($path) {
//should execute for all paths after common
})->where('path', 'YOUR REGEX GOES HERE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using below code.

```
Route::any('/common/{args?}', function($args){
   $args = explode('/', $args);
   // do your code by passing argument to controller
})->where('args', '(.*)');
```